# How do I replace logo targeting event pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, squarespace

I'm using a Squarespace theme where normally the light logo looks okay on top of the header images. The problem is we've added a calendar and the event pages do not have a header image and so the white logo disappears on the white background.

## Code Attempted

I want to replace the logo only on the event pages with a logo that can site on white. I've tried entering the code below without any luck.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   if (window.location.href.indexOf("event-calendar") > -1) {
   $('.Header-branding').find('img').attr('src', 'https://static1.squarespace.com/Business-Logo-Events.png')
 }

});
</script>
```

How do I replace the logo on my event pages?

### Optional Pertinant Info

File path for event pages: */event-calendar*
Event pages unique class in body of all event pages: *.collection-type-events*

HTML of Logo:

```
<a href="/" class="Header-branding">
  <img src="logo.png" alt="" class="Header-branding-logo">          
</a>
```

Comment: Oops nice catch. Let me fix that and give it another try.

Comment: Just updated my post with what I entered, but not luck correcting that.

Comment: If you inspect the element, is the attr what you expect it should be?

Comment: Yes, it is the correct attribute.

Comment: So you're saying that inspecting the img, the attr is correct, but the displayed image is not?  Edit: I just tried sticking your img url in a browser url, and its not returning a picture.

Comment: Yes, but specifically the `src` which you didn't capture in that screenshot

Comment: Ah gotcha, the src does not match the src I specified in my jQuery <https://static1.squarespace.com/Business-Logo-Events.png>

Comment: For shiggles, try changing `attr()` to `prop()`

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Comment: Alright, so it's one of those weird situations.  `src` is both an attribute from the source, but also a property on the Element in the DOM.  Changing one doesn't necessarily change the other.  So in this case we wanted to update the one that the browser uses for actually rendering the image, which is the Element property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer credit goes to @Taplar

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   if (window.location.href.indexOf("event-calendar") > -1) {
   $('.Header-branding').find('img').prop('src', 
 'https://static1.squarespace.com/Business-Logo-Events.png')
 }

});
</script>
```